Video logo clock ffmpeg
With the codes I created myself, the time setting does not appear. Only the screw logo and the movie name appears. I could not make this time setting. Are there any friends who can help me?
ffmpeg -i James.Bond.1971.mkv -i logo.png -filter_complex "[1:v] scale=100:-1 [logo]; [0:v][logo] overlay=10:10, drawtext=fontfile='/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf':text='James Bond 1971':x=w-tw-10:y=h-th-10:fontsize=24:fontcolor=white:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5, drawtext=fontfile='/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf':text='%{pts\:hms}':x=10:y=h-th-10:fontsize=24:fontcolor=white:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5" -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset fast James.Bond.1971cikti.mkv
What I want should be something like this:

and what i did the clock in the picture is ticking very fast, I don't want it to tick that fast. I couldn't do it anyway.


Hello, please try to use more proper English, with Google Translate or anything similar. E.g. I don't quite understand what you mean by "ticking too fast" or "time setting".
